# Unchecked checkbox validation returns error of [object Object]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using jquery to send checked and unchecked checkboxes to a PHP validation form. 
The jquery used is:

```
 'updates'  : $('input:checkbox[name=updates]').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0
```

I think I must be validating wrong as this returns [object Object] what is the best way to resolve his?

The javascript validation form used to send the formData

```
function validateForm() {
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Sending...";
formData = {
'name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(),
'surname'  : $('input[name=surname]').val(),
'email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(),
'subject'  : $('input[name=subject]').val(),
'message'  : $('textarea[name=message]').val(),
'updates'  : $('input:checkbox[name=updates]').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0
};


$.ajax({
url : "mail.php",
type: "POST",
data : formData,
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{

$('#status').text(data.message);
if (data.code) //If mail was sent successfully, reset the form.
$('#contact-form').closest('form').find("input[type=text], 
textarea").val("");
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{   
$('#status').text(jqXHR);
}
});

}
```

The PHP validation on the server side

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$updates= $_POST['updates'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if ($updates){
 print json_encode(array('message' => 'Checkbox cannot be empty', 
                        'code' => 0));
} else{

exit();
}

$content="From: $name \nSurname: $surname \nEmail: $email \nMessage: 
$message";
$recipient = "*******@gmail.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email successfully sent!',
'code' 
=> 
1));
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see `[object Object]`?

Comment: Why are you doing any of that? Just get the checked checkbox's value and send that.

Comment: Yes Karl I only see [object Object] returned

Comment: I was doing it this way as I thought I could validate if it was checked easier, I maybe wrong and unsure how best to do it ? what would you recommend ? maybe 'updates'  : $("input:checkbox[name=updates]:not(:checked)"); but then I am unsure on the php validation for that.

Comment: Isn't this the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143854/validating-checked-checkboxes-using-php-when-checkbox-is-sent-as-a-1) you asked yesterday?

Comment: yes, I tried to add the main detail straight away to help. My posts only really get responses in the first 12hr.

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you see when you try to use a Javascript object in a place where a string is needed. It doesn't come from PHP.

Comment: Maybe you're going to the `error:` callback. `$('#status').text(jqXHR);` will display that, since `jqXHR` is an object.

Comment: Try using `$("#status").text(textStatus)` instead to see the error message.

Comment: i suggest validate in client side example: var updates=$('input:checkbox[name=updates]').val();   if(updates == "" || updates == null){alert("don't checked");}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get wrong value because on `$updates == 1` you printed 2 different JSON. Change you PHP script with that.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$updates= $_POST['updates'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if ($updated == 0){
 print json_encode(array('message' => 'Checkbox cannot be empty', 
                        'code' => 0));
} else{
$content="From: $name \nSurname: $surname \nEmail: $email \nMessage: 
$message";
$recipient = "*******@gmail.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email successfully sent!',
'code' 
=> 
1));
}
?>
```

Comment: Holy Moly!!!!!! Its working!!!!!!!!  needed to exit after the else but its working :) Thank you so much.